# debian for truecrypt-7.1a for ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, debian, truecrypt

I am unable to find debian package for truecrypt-7.1a version. Any idea where should i look for this debian? Please share if you have source code of truecrypt and steps for creating debian package for same.

Answer (score 1):

Im pretty sure TrueCrypt is a dead project. I don’t think you’ll see new packages coming out, and I dont think the mainline debian devs will be touching it either. Here is an article on why:
http://krebsonsecurity.com/2014/05/true-goodbye-using-truecrypt-is-not-secure/

Comment: In addition to the above Steve Gibson has some excellent work and the last known 'good source' for TrueCrypt. You can check it out and decide for yourself by clicking [here](https://www.grc.com/misc/truecrypt/truecrypt.htm).

Comment: Appreciate your help. I have below queries on debian creation for truecrypt -7.1a. I have briefly browsed through the links that you have shared. It seems like truecrypt - 7.1a is still secure and we can use the same. But there is no debian package available for the same.                              As there are some repositories like PPA in github which has debian support for truecrypt-7.1a. My question is how PPA repository differs from main Ubuntu repository? Is it secure / proper to go ahead and use those repositories? Please share your suggestion. Thank you.